# Gebish groovy script failed failed to create driver from callback

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy

I try to run TCS from internet:

https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle

Under windows but I get errors:

```
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script1473865059036142656175$_run_closure2$_closure4$_closure7@7cbfc9e7'

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: \Temp\anonymous1762webdriver-profile\extensions.json.tmp (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Does anybody know what could have happened?

One of the files is:

```
  import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

    ext {
        // The drivers we want to use
        drivers = ["firefox", "chrome", "phantomJs"]

        ext {
            groovyVersion = '2.4.5'
            gebVersion = '0.13.1'
            seleniumVersion = '2.51.0'
            chromeDriverVersion = '2.19'
            phantomJsVersion = '1.9.7'
        }
    }
```

Should I run from cmd selenium-java-server?
(When I tried I got: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.)
Thanks!